# SVM model averaging in sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, ensemble-learning

l would like to average the scores of two different SVMs trained on different samples but same classes

```
# Data have the smae label x_1[1] has y_1[1] and x_2[1] has y_2[1]
# Where y_2[1] == y_1[1]
Dataset_1=(x_1,y)
Dataset_2=(x_2,y)
test_data=(test_sample,test_labels)
```

We have 50 classes. Same classes for dataset_1 and dataset_2 :

```
list(set(y_1))=list(set(y_2))
```

What l have tried :

from sklearn.svm import SVC

```
clf_1 = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=42).fit(x_1, y)

clf_2 = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=42).fit(x_2, y)
```

How to average clf_1 and clf_2 scores before doing :

```
predict(test_sample)
```

?

What l would like to do ?

Comment: What do you mean by averaging the score and that too before predict()

Comment: l mean by that the ensemble learning with averaging score. Each SVM output a score for each class, l would like to sum each class score and divide by 2 (to get a mean) and output the final results after combining the two SVMs. Concretely my question is about how to average the scores ? It can be done by the averaging or training a third SVM that combines the two svms scores. My question is about that (l'm not familiar with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question; to simply average the scores as in a typical ensemble, you should first get prediction [*probabilities*](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba) from each model separately, and then just take their average:

```
pred1 = clf_1.predict_proba(test_sample)
pred2 = clf_2.predict_proba(test_sample)
pred = (pred1 + pred2)/2
```

In order to get prediction probabilities instead of hard classes, you should initialize the SVC using the additional argument `probability=True`.

Each row of `pred` will be an array of length 50, as many as your classes, with each element representing the probability that the sample belongs to the respective class.

After averaging, simply take the argmax of `pred` - just be sure that the *order* of the returned probabilities is OK; according to the docs:

> The columns correspond to the classes in sorted order, as they appear in the attribute classes_

As I am not exactly sure what this means, run some checks with predictions on your training set, to be sure that the order is correct.

Comment: let's take an example test , test_sample[1] then pred1 = clf_1.predict(test_sample[1])  returns pred1 returns class 4 and pred2 = clf_2.predict(test_sample[1]) returns  class 9.  pred = (pred1 + pred2)/2  then pred return class 6.5 !!